# Можно ли определить generics тип класса

Tags: java

Есть класс:

```
class<T> {
}
```

Можно ли как-то определить тип `Т`, **не** передавая его в конструктор?

Comment: Нет, нельзя, так как на стадии компиляции `T` "превратится в тыкву"

Comment: Конкретно в Java нельзя из-за _type erasure_.

Comment: Можно вообще-то, используя рефлексию и getGenericSuperclass и getGenericInterfaces методы, но очень бы не рекомендовал это использовать.

Comment: @ViacheslavVedenin, разве для приведённого примера там окажется не Object независимо от вызова?

Comment: А не важно, я написал код в ответе ниже, даже при Object'е будет работать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На самом деле, можно используя рефлексию и `getGenericSuperclass` / `getGenericInterfaces` / `getTypeParameters` (хотя и считается, что информация о дженериках в Java стирается), но крайне не рекомендуется (рефлексия и все дела, к тому же не уверен, что этот фокус будет работать во всех случаях и на любой JVM). Проверьте следующий код:

```
public class TestClass {
    class MyClass extends OtherClass<GenericClass>{

        String myName;
        //Whatever

    }

    class OtherClass<T> {

        T myfield;

    }

    class GenericClass {
        String field;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
       OtherClass<GenericClass> ttt = new MyClass();
       ParameterizedType t = (ParameterizedType) ttt.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
       Class<?> cls = (Class<?>) t.getActualTypeArguments()[0]; //
       System.out.println(cls);  // напечатает TestClass#GenericClass
    }    
}
```

Обычно намного проще и быстрее просто передавать параметр Class cls в нужную функцию. Более того будет работать даже такой код (проверьте)

```
    Object ttt = new MyClass();
    ParameterizedType t = (ParameterizedType) ttt.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    Class<?> cls = (Class<?>) t.getActualTypeArguments()[0]; 
    System.out.println(cls); // напечатает TestClass#GenericClass
```

Можно так же узнать generic даже если нет child'а, например так

```
    Object ttt = new OtherClass<GenericClass>();
    TypeVariable[] a1 = ttt.getClass().getTypeParameters();
    System.out.println(a1[0].getGenericDeclaration()); // напечатает TestClass#GenericClass
```

Мало кто знает, что миф о том что информация о generic теряется всегда и в любой JVM уже не актуален, другое дело стоит ли использовать настолько **черную магию**?

Answer (score 5):

Дженерики существуют только на момент компиляции, в рантайме, когда приложение выполняется информации о дженериках стирается. Тип дженерика нельзя определить ни через мета информацию о полях класса, ни через метаинформацию о методах класса(принимаемые параметры, возвращаемый тип). Так же в java нельзя создать инстанс дженеричной переменной. Следовательно получить тип дженеричной переменной класса, не имея ее инстанса невозможно.

Если у вас есть возможность получить инстанс переменной-дженерика(через рефлексию), то его тип можно определить не передавая его в конструктор, иначе ответ нет, нельзя.