# можно ли проверить тип параметра generic

Tags: java, compare

Можно ли проверить непосредственно тип самого параметра  в классе generic? типа этого?

```
class ComparatorBack<T> implements Comparator<T> {

@Override
public int compare(T o1, T o2) {

    if (T instanceof Person) {

        if (((Person)o1).age == ((Person)o2).age) {
            return 0;
        } else if (((Person)o1).age < ((Person)o2).age) {
            return 1;
        } else if (((Person)o1).age > ((Person)o2).age) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
 }}
```

Comment: либо можно `<? extends Person>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно проверить только типы объектов, типов generic'ов вообще в рантайме нет.

```
if (o1 instanceof Person && o2 instanceof Person) {
  ...
}

return o1 instanceof Person ? -1 : 1;
```

Comment: что значит в типов generic'ов вообще в рантайме нет. а не в рантайме?

Comment: @АлексейСемёнов, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/742252/178988

Comment: @АлексейСемёнов обобщения - это указания компилятору, после компиляции они [стираются](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). В райнтайме ваша `T` - это `Object`.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать все намного проще

```
class ComparatorBack implements Comparator<Person> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
        return Integer.compare(o2.age, o1.age);
    }
}
```

Ключевым будет то, что мы сразу имплементируем интерфейс `Comparator`, у которого generic будет `Person`

Comment: так тоже делал, спасибо. Но я учу язык и его возможности, поэтому хотелось  узнать непосредственно про параметр <T>

Comment: @АлексейСемёнов необходимость проверять типы в рантайме - это в большинстве случаев признак плохой архитектуры. Старайтесь избегать этого.